# Azure log analytics creating line chart from query

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I have few VMs of which logs I would like to create log analytics view. I have set that all commands are logged into file. Log is created with this line:

```
"[ON]:\$(date)   [FROM]:\${IP}   [USER]:\${USER}   [PWD]:\${PWD}"
```

Logs come to my log analytics workspace just fine and I can find those with query:

```
CustomLog_CL | where _ResourceId contains "secure"
```

However, when I try to have that as a line chart for the overview tile it just always says "Oops I cannot get data". I have tried adding count and expanding the time range without any affect.

How can I get this into line chart?

Comment: Can you show us the entire query and the screenshot? Since the data is in CustomLog_CL, there is no reason that it cannot convert to line chart. If I'm misunderstanding, please correct me.

Comment: The second one is the entire query I am using to find those log lines. I am not sure which screenshot I should take so it would help.

Comment: Are you using azure portal -> log analytics -> log query? if that's the case, please show us the screenshot  of that screen when you're querying and include the errors.

Comment: Yes I am using that. The problem is that query is working fine when I do the query via log query. However, it does not work when I am trying to use that same query on the overview tile. Error message says "the request had some invalid properties" and if I open it says "Invalid resource ID (must be subscription, resource group or resource)"

Comment: I'm not clear "overview tile", can you point me that?

Comment: in log analytics you can get to "workspace summary", that will show "overview tiles" for views. that is what I am trying to get, new view but failing to get the overview tile working.